# Solving $\int \arcsin(x) \ln(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am having trouble with the following integral:

$$\int \arcsin(x) \ln(x)dx$$

I tried solving it by parts and trig substituted  which ended horribly
$$ =(x\ln(x)-x)\arcsin(x)-\int\frac{x\ln(x)-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx $$
$$\int\frac{x\ln(x)-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx= \int\frac{\sin(x)(\ln(\sin(x))-1)}{\cos(x)\sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}}dx $$
u-substitution does not seem viable to solve this integral

How do you solve this integral? Is there any tricky awful u sub that you need to do to initially? I am trying to stay away from complex analysis and solve using elementary techniques.

Comment: Where is it from? A book question?

Comment: @Buraian A friend gave it to me. I don't even know if it is solvable. Does that help ?

Comment: Usually friends give integrals without closed forms, so be careful :-). Your friend seems to be nice :https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/508301105663574026/883213966275379220/wolf.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integration by parts is the play. Differentiate $\ln(x)$ and integrate $\sin^{-1}(x)$. We get

\begin{align}
\int \sin^{-1}(x)\ln(x)dx &= \left(x\sin^{-1}(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\ln(x)-\int\frac{x\sin^{-1}(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} dx\\
&= \left(x\sin^{-1}(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\ln(x)-\int\left(\sin^{-1}(x)+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right)dx
\end{align}

Can you continue?

Comment: I was about to do that :-(

Comment: Thank you very much. Yep that's easy enough thank you for your help

Comment: @hwood87 glad I could help :)